# Android: what kind of menu layout is this?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, menu, menuitem

I want to make an menu for my app just like on this picture from Instapaper app
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwLrx.jpg](https://lh3.ggpht.com/PjOttZyCLZK2eGvQCshWOjwdfRaK9iOUCqqgWgGeg9g4ygaN_BY6i8c6PeFoSl5Mt1w_)

So the menu overlays the part of the current activity and when taking actions from the menu, the effect is seen immediately and the menu does not close after applying a single action.

What kind of layout is this? How can I implement it? Or is it some kind of a library?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like a custom xml layout.

Comment: What causes the "menu" to appear? It could be a `SlidingDrawer` - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Comment: @Squonk well, but SlidingDrawer is deprecated now, so it is not a really good idea to use it then

Answer (score 3):

That's certainly and definitely a custom implementation from the developers.

Most likely an XML layout inflated and animated when you call the menu.